# Needing Help Separating Data into columns

Tags: sql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm currently using SQL at work to Query a database in order to display certain information. I have each item that's being pulled as separate entities. Whenever I run the Query my results only show under one column. Is there a way to separate this data into separate columns based on alias?

```
SELECT
    count(o.orderid) AS Current_Daily
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.ship_dt BETWEEN '2020-11-09 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-15 23:59:59'
    AND o.orderstatus = 2
UNION
#UNION ALL

SELECT
    count(o.orderid)  AS Previous_Daily
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.ship_dt BETWEEN '2019-11-09 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-15 23:59:59'
    AND o.orderstatus = 2
UNION
#UNION ALL

SELECT
    count(o.orderid) AS Current_Monthly
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.ship_dt BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-15 23:59:59'
    AND o.orderstatus = 2
UNION
#UNION ALL

SELECT
    count(o.orderid) AS Previous_Monthly
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.ship_dt BETWEEN '2019-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-15 23:59:59'
    AND o.orderstatus = 2

;
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.  It is unclear why you repeat two of the same queries twice, except for the column alias.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation, as in:

```
select
    sum(case when ship_dt >= '2020-11-09' and ship_dt < '2020-11-15' then 1 else 0 end) as current_daily,
    sum(case when ship_dt >= '2020-11-01' and ship_dt < '2020-11-15' then 1 else 0 end) as current_monthly,
    ... -- more conditional "sum()"s if needed
from orders o
where orderstatus = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN o.ship_dt >= '2020-11-09' AND o.ship_dt < '2020-11-16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Current_Daily,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.ship_dt >= '2020-11-01' AND o.ship_dt < '2020-11-16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Current_Monthly,
FROM orders o
WHERE o.orderstatus = 2;
```

You can add additional columns using similar logic.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm needing this data separated, I wasn't sure if I clarified that or not. Each output has to exist on its own. I'm merely trying to create a more legible readout that states exactly what is being shown

Comment: count(o.orderid)
462
573
841
1321


Here is the data output I'm getting from this query. I'm simply wanting to just separate each of these results out into separately labeled columns.